# How can I store types in go maps for initialisation at a later stage

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a factory function that will return an instance of one of many structs that fulfil the contract of an interface `X`.

```
m := make(map[string] ?)
func init () {
    m["a"] = ?
    m["b"] = ?
}

type X interface { 
    y()
}

type A struct {}
func (a * A) y () {}

type B struct {}
func (b * B) y () {}


function factory(name string) X {
    return &m[name]{}
}
```

The code above is just a simplified demonstration of what I'm trying to achieve - looking for pointers for whether this is possible, or if there is a different go idiom to solve this kind of requirement that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map[string]X`, with X the interface (which can reference a value or a pointer of any object respecting X contract)

> or if there is a different go idiom to solve this kind of requirement that I'm missing?

You can also use reflection (as in "[Instance new Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10211940/6309)") to implement your factory.

```
reflect.New(yourtype).Elem().Interface()
```

You can see a factory example in "[is there a way to create an instance of a struct from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23031445/6309)".

---

The quicker approach for a factory method (returning a new instance each time) is using a switch (like [in this example](https://github.com/go-goodies/go_oops/blob/0e93be7326745a30de943fb72211495227934525/factory_method_with_reuse/widget.go#L63-L72)):

```
// Create a new Widget interface based on WidgetType and set WidgetInfo
func New(wt WidgetType, wi WidgetInfo) Widget_iface {
    switch wt {
    case Widget_A:
        return newWidgetA(wi)
    case Widget_B:
        return newWidgetB(wi)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Looks like theres a minor additional overhead of registering the type using an instance but I guess that instance will be garbage collected reasonably quickly?

Comment: @Ali-AkberSaifee yes, it will. But in general reflection is slower so if you intend to call your factory hundreds of time per second, a map is quicker.

Comment: @Ali-AkberSaifee do you want your factory to return a *new* instance of A or B? If yes, I have edited the answer.

Comment: for my current usecase I'm ok with just getting a new instance - but in terms of trying to understand the language I'm curious if I can return just the type

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple value type then as @VonC said, you can just use `map[string]X` and return a copy of the exemplar value.

For anything else, instead of using reflection, I'd just use a map of creation functions. Like what the `image` package does with
[`image.RegisterFormat`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#RegisterFormat).

E.g. ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SJyNCNDQ5t)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type X interface {
        y()
}

type newXFunc func() X

// Here just a map variable and two functions, but
// this could be a type with two methods instead.

var m = map[string]newXFunc{}

func register(name string, fn newXFunc) {
        m[name] = fn
}

func factory(name string) X {
        return m[name]()
}

func init() {
        // If register is exported than these
        // calls can be in other packages that
        // implement A and B.
        register("a", NewA)
        // For simple things that don't have/need
        // their own stand-alone "new" function.
        register("b", func() X { return B{} })
}

type A struct{}

func (a *A) y() {}
func NewA() X   { return &A{} }

type B struct{}

func (b B) y() {}

func main() {
        a1 := factory("a")
        b1 := factory("b")
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", a1)
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", b1)
}
```

Comment: A map of functions is more efficient than my answer. +1