# Dynamically instantiate a Type in Golang

Tags: types, go

From what I've seen this is probably not possible at the moment in Golang, but I'll ask this question anyway.

Given this Type

```
type Foo struct {
  ....
}
```

I would like to be able to instantiate this type, using reflection for instance, just by using its name "Foo".

Something along these lines

```
foo := New("Foo")
```

Is it possible?

Comment: There is also the assignment of something of varying type to a variable, which will have to be an interface that handles any methods that foo will eventually call.  So foo will have to be definied as 'var foo InterfaceType = Factory("Foo")' or some such.  See https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types for more on interfaces as well as the above on reflection.

Comment: Yes, my post looks like a duplicate of the [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210188/instance-new-type-golang]. I think I'll probably use the suggestion from that post - maintain a map that keeps track of the Types that should be used in the application.