# How to call method by its string name with string struct name?

Tags: go, methods, dynamic, struct

I have one struct with 2 methods under struct definition, I want to call in other place that use struct's name and method's name as param.

Struct code as following:

```
type ArticleForm struct {
Name     string     `required:"true" pattern:"^[A-Za-z0-9\u4e00-\u9fa5]{1,1024}$" valid:"Required;MaxSize(1024)"`
Category []Category `class:"multis" required:"true" valid:"Required" optionqs:"GetCategoryOption"`
Content  string     `class:"wysiwg_area" required:"true" valid:"Required"`
Tags     []Tags     `class:"multis_create" optionqs:"GetTagOptions"`
}
```

Method definition as following:

```
func (this *ArticleForm) GetTagOptions() []Tags {
return GetTagsOptions(nil)
}
```

Following is what I want to call:

```
func main() {
s := "models.ArticleForm"
t := "GetTagOptions"
//following is the question, how can i exec following?
funcall(s,t)
}
```

How to fulfill the `funcall(s,t)`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210188/instance-new-type-golang for creating an instance of a type given a string.

Comment: Switch Case can be a simple solution.

Answer (score 26):

Calling a method of some type given by its name is easy (using [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)). See this example:

```
type My struct{}

func (m My) MyFunc() {
    fmt.Println("MyFunc called")
}

func main() {
    m := My{}
    meth := reflect.ValueOf(m).MethodByName("MyFunc")
    meth.Call(nil)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NPUerRL8_I)):

```
MyFunc called
```

"Instantiating" a type given its string name is not possible, because if your code does not explicitly refer to the type, it may not even be included in the executable binary. For details, see [Call all functions with special prefix or suffix in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384473/call-all-functions-with-special-prefix-or-suffix-in-golang/37384665#37384665); and [Splitting client/server code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875016/splitting-client-server-code/38875901#38875901).

A possible workaround is to use some kind of "type-registry" which you populate prior to using it (before you want to create a value by its name). The type registry (which may be a map) may hold [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) values or factory functions mapped from the type name.

Following the above `My` type declaration, a type registry storing `reflect.Type` values may look like this (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/v5s_j7xnHW)):

```
registry := map[string]reflect.Type{
    "My": reflect.TypeOf((*My)(nil)).Elem(),
}

v := reflect.New(registry["My"]).Elem()
v.MethodByName("MyFunc").Call(nil)
```

And a registry that stores factory functions could look like this (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rZOa-6AfM5)):

```
registry := map[string]func() interface{}{
    "My": func() interface{} { return My{} },
}

v := registry["My"]()
meth := reflect.ValueOf(v).MethodByName("MyFunc")
meth.Call(nil)
```

Comment: how to add arguments to `MyFunc`?

Comment: @MohNj Like this: `func (m My) MyFunc(paramName paramType) {}`

Comment: Is there a way I can call them without reflection? I was thinking of adapter pattern. Any thoughts on the same?

Comment: @karthikeyan The linked question shows other ways to call it: [Call functions with special prefix/suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384473/call-functions-with-special-prefix-suffix/37384665#37384665)